# Array_unique and XLS export

Tags: php, arrays, xls

So I want to export my database to XLS format... Here is my code

```
$req_test = $db->prepare('SELECT `surname`, `name`, `num`, `email`, `password`, `rank` FROM staff');
$req_test->execute();


$array = $req_test->fetchAll();

$array = array_unique($array);

print_r($array);


header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo.xls\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
foreach ($array as $data)
{
fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");
}
fclose($out);
```

So without the array_unique it return this :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [surname] => test [0] => test [name] => test [1] => test [num] => 2424242424 [2] => 2424242424 [email] => test@gmail.com [3] => test@gmail.com [password] => 123456 [4] => 123456 [rank] => admin [5] => admin ) [1] => Array ( [surname] => Markus [0] => Markus [name] => Tasse [1] => Tasse [num] => 052424524 [2] => 052424524 [email] => ad@gmail.com [3] => ad@gmail.com [password] => us01PjIOx2 [4] => us01PjIOx2 [rank] => staff [5] => staff ) )
```

And with I have this error :

```
( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp3.2.0\www\project\export.php on line 15
```

What can I do ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know which is "line 15" in your code, but if that line is the "fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");" i guess you need to flatten the $data variable before pretending to output it to a file just like if it was a string. I guess that your $data variable hold all the fields you've pasted, so either u pick them 1by1 or it won't work i guess

Comment: So everything is working but the array_unique is making an error.

Comment: What do you actually expect from array_unique?

Comment: To remove the cloned entry

Comment: I guess you should get the unique data directly from your SQL query, w/o having to bother yourself doing that in PHP